# Smallest Width qualifiers not working Android Studio

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-xml

I have added dimensions files for each screen size range using SW modifier, and
i did some changes to values

[image]

then i made a style out of these dimensions, but when i switch to the preview i get the following error without noticing any changes in the layout [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need another `dimens.xml` for those layouts that aren't covered by your 3 files. This will be the default values to fall back upon. It would sit in `/values/` folder just like `styles.xml`

Comment: i have added the dimens.xml, and the error is gone, but i still have the problem to get all devices using there required dimens, for example (Nexus 5X,6P,6,5,4,Galaxy,S and One) all skips all dimens and settle on the base one, i have tried to lower SW of 480dp to (300,200...) but nothing seems to work tho !

Comment: so your question is answered :-)

for your new question, try something simpler like `layout` and `layout-land`, to make sure you understand how it works